# Speed control actuator in a two-actuator setup, joystick controlled

Tags: actuator, joystick

I have two 12 VDC actuators connected to a 4-position joystick.
I need to be able to control the speed of one actuator only; the other will run at full speed.

Could you draw and/or explain how I could to wire a 12 VDC speed controller into this circuit? If I put in the motor-out contacts it doesn't work because the power polarities change when the joystick is in a reverse position.

Maybe I have to run two complete circuits, but how do I wire the joystick controller?

[image]

Comment: What is your joystick? How does it work on the inside? What is the meaning of T/B/R/L pins? All we can say from the picture is that it's some kind of 'magic box' wit 8 pins

Comment: What are the boxes near the motors? Are they relays? In current configuration shown on the picture it looks like they are in short-circuit position when the motors are off.

Comment: Hi the boxes are relays . the t/b/ etc relate to the Top set of switches or the Bottom set

Comment: see the page from where i did the setup

Comment: dont know how to paste a pic so heres the link https://www.instructables.com/Rocker-Switch-and-Joystick-Wiring-w-Linear-Actuato/